# Vim: open quickfix window automatically when warnings are encountered

Tags: latex, vim

I have a function to build my tex files that will open the quickfix window if there are errors during the compilation process. However if a warning is encountered the quickfix window remains closed. How can I modify the function to open the quickfix window when there are warnings?

```
function! CompileTex()
    exec "lcd %:h"     
    set makeprg=arara\ -v
    silent make %

    if v:shell_error
        copen
    else
        cclose
        redraw
        echon "successfully compiled"
    endif
endfunction
```

If I manually open the quickfix window it shows that there is a warning but I would like to do this automatically.

Comment: I don't know much about tex compilation. However the `:compiler tex` should set `'makeprg'` for you (if it isn't done automatically). You can also do `let g:tex_flavor = 'arara -v'` to use a different program. If you do want to build your own function I suggest you look  at `:h :cwindow` and `:h getqflist()`. Your function currently has some side effects: `lcd` and changing `'makeprg'`. These might have unforeseen consequence down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `'makeprg'`'s exit status (`v:shell_error`) to determine whether to open the quickfix window. The tool presumably returns *success* (0) if only warnings occurred.

Change the conditional to open the quickfix window whenever there are captured items (note: not necessarily warnings, for that you need additional checking; the elements returned by `getqflist()` have a `type` attribute for that):

```
if ! empty(getqflist())
    copen
...
```

Comment: I solved that problem (I was setting wrongly the error format). One additional question: how do I tell the make program to expand to the full path without changing the working directory (i.e deleting the line `exec "lcd %:h"` in my OP)? I tried setting `makeprg=arara\ -v\ %:p` but the compiler complains that it cannot find the file. Maybe special character need to be escaped?

Comment: Yes, `%:p` expands to an absolute path, but not every program can deal with that. What's so bad about the `:lcd`?!

Comment: A comment in the original post said that it "might have unforeseen consequence down the road" so I thought that the way I was doing it was wrong. Now everything works perfectly but for instance if there are compile errors in my document, the .aux file is opened and the cursor jumps to that buffer. Do you know how to tell the quickfix window to only report errors and allow me to jump and open a specific file only when I hit enter?